# On Facebook does the user get notified when a non-friend comments on their post which they posted on their friend's wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

If I post something on a friend's timeline, and a friend of theirs (but not a friend of mine) comments on that post, will I get a notification?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will get a notification when anyone likes, comments on, or shares that post.